# Array of Objects Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, oop, jdbc, struts

I am creating an array of objects like this

```
            RMCUser[] rmc = new RMCUser[resultList.size()];
            int i = 0;

            for (Iterator iter = resultList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object[] objArr = (Object[]) iter.next();

        appl_id = objArr[0].toString();
        rmc[i].setAppl_id(appl_id);
                       i++}
```

I get a nullpointer exception in the `rmc[i].setAppl_id` line.
My `resultList` size is 1.

Comment: because `rmc[i]` is null

Comment: where do you populate your rmc array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never initializing the values in the array. When you create an array and don't explicitly initialize the values in it they default to an appropriate value based on the type. In your case, `null`.

The fix is to explicitly initialize each value.

```
RMCUser[] rmc = new RMCUser[resultList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < rmc.length(); i++)
{
    rmc[i] = new RMCUser();
    ... // do whatever else you need to do with it here
}
```